# react native html postMessage can not reach to WebView

Tags: javascript, html, webview, react-native, postmessage

I use React Native webview to show `index.html`, and HTML will post messge to the app. The app will then receive the message and write it to console. The problem is the app cannot receive messages, when `postMessage` is immediately run on head. I think it maybe related to HTML not finished loading. I then used a delay with `setTimeout`, and it worked.

Now I want to know:

- Is there better way to solve this problem?
- Why the delay 100 milliscond did not work, but delay 200 milliscond did?

I am using React Native version 0.39.0, and Node version 7.2.0.

Here is the code I have so far:

index.html

```
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // can not be received
    postMessage('send to react native from index inline, no delay', '*');

    // can not be received
    setTimeout(function(){
        postMessage('send to react native from index inline, delay 0 milliscond', '*')
    }, 0);

    // can received
    setTimeout(function(){
        postMessage('send to react native from index inline, delay 100 milliscond', '*')
    }, 100);

    onload = function() {
        // can not be received
        postMessage('send to react native from index inline after onload, no delay', '*')

        // can received
        setTimeout(function () {
            postMessage('send to react native from index inline after onload, delay 0 milliscond', '*')
        }, 0);
    };
</script>
```

index.js

```
// can not be received
postMessage('send to react native from index.js, no delay', '*');

// can not be received
setTimeout(function() {
    postMessage('send to react native from index.js, delay 100 milliscond', '*')
}, 100);

// can received
setTimeout(function() {
    postMessage('send to react native from index.js, delay 200 milliscond', '*')
}, 200);
```

React Native web_view_page.js

```
return (
        <WebView
            source={{uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html'}}
            onMessage={(event) => console.log('onMessage:', event.nativeEvent.data)}/>
    );
```

Chrome console log

```
2016-12-21 11:45:02.367 web_view.js:147 onMessage: send to react native from index inline after onload, delay 0 milliscond
2016-12-21 11:45:02.491 web_view.js:147 onMessage: send to react native from index inline, delay 100 milliscond
2016-12-21 11:45:02.628 web_view.js:147 onMessage: send to react native from index.js, delay 200 milliscond
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you've found your answer by now, but in the event you have not or if other people are in need then check out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594.

Basically, you need to wait for the `postMessage` to be present in the window before we can successfully post messages.

```
function onBridgeReady(cb) {
  if (window.postMessage.length !== 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      onBridgeReady(cb)
    }, 100);
  } else {
    cb();
  }
}

onBridgeReady(function() {
  window.postMessage('Bridge is ready and WebView can now successfully receive messages.');
});
```

**Source: [Andrei Barabas](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594#issuecomment-281232273)**